# Connecting 2 different tables with same data but different granularity

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have a 2 tables for customer support performance analysis, and they are virtually the same but the problem is the 2 columns are different. The one data has a date column, and the other data has hour of day column(going from 0-23) I need somehow to connect these 2 tables in Power bi so I don't have to make 2 separate reports. Cause I would rather have them connected and then have a drill down option that includes also by hour of the day??? I do have a contact id column but when i try to make a relationship it only gives me many to many which is not what I need.

I tried makin a connection on contact id that is in the both of column but only relationship that I have is many to many. Second thing that i try is doing left outer join in merge queries but I didn't get desired result. It was a lot of nulls and some of the column had the same values for all rows. I also tried to create a composite key but also not desired result only many to many relationship. Unfortunately i do not have an access to sql so is there any way how this can be done without that.